# python - data structure for fast add, remove, and random choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I need a data structure for adding items, removing items, and picking a random item.

From what I've read, I think picking a random item from a list with `random.choice` takes constant time. However, removing an item from a list takes O(n) time.

On the other hand, removing and adding an item from/to to a set take O(1) time, but picking a random element from a set with `random.sample` takes O(n) time.

Is there a way to support those three operations in O(1) time?

Comment: shufle the list, pop items. shuffling is O(n) , popping is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dict?
I know it's a little weird, but on average dict lookup and insertion is O(1). And you can use random.choice on it as it supports indexing!

Here is a graph showing the amount of time it takes to use random.choice on a dict. The x-axis is the size of the dict and the y-axis is time.

[image]

Comment: From the source code, `random.choice(d)` picks a random integer from integer `i` from 0 to `len(d)` and returns `d[i]`. If you suggest using items as keys and the items are not integers, then this would result in KeyError.

Comment: You could use a unique integer for each element. For example the time.time at which it was inserted.

Comment: Let's say `d[0] = item0` and `d[2] = item2`. This could result in KeyError if `d[1]` is called and `d[2]` would never be picked. Again, the data structure needs to support quick add and remove as well.

Comment: You are correct..

Comment: An alternative could be to use a counter, and use it as the key of each element. It's not the prettiest solution, but it is efficient.

Comment: What would I do for removing an element?

Comment: Removing an element is another problem.. I may have overlooked it. A solution could be to have a sort of "hash" function to use on elements. It's use will be in generating the keys for insertion and deletion of elements from the dict. For example if you turn "hello World" into the key 5 using this "hash", you will be able to use it for `dict[5] = "hello World"` and `del dict[5]`. Both operation being O(1). The hash function being the only bottleneck.